# Getting this message act worksheet not saved in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I often get this message; plz see screenshot
[image]

may I know what causes this message to appear? And which option is the best to choose. Help is appreciated.

Comment: It typically means you're logged in somewhere else, like in another browser tab, and altering the same worksheet.  You can save to a new worksheet and then review both worksheets to ensure you're not losing anything.  Feel free to log out everywhere and clear the browser cache, possibly restart the computer, if it keeps happening so you don't have multiple sessions open.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't open the same worksheet on several browser tabs at the same time, this error won't happen.

If you happen to modify the worksheet in different tabs concurrently, the safe option is to "save to a new worksheet" - so both versions of the worksheet can survive.